# Bulk insert into postgresql wiwth Insert

Tags: postgresql

I have a test database where I basically want to run this command 100,000 times. How do I do this?

```
insert into order_requests(order_id, order_request_id)values(2, uuid_generate_v4());
```

I want to in short run that above insert 100,000 times and create that many new records. What's the best way to do this in postgresql?

Comment: You want all `order_id`  to be `2`?

Comment: If its a sequence and all unique numbers, even better

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into order_requests(order_id, order_request_id)
select i, uuid_generate_v4()
from generate_series(1, 100000) gs(i)
```